# Has any corporation ever organised internal market-based competition between its teams?

Tags: business-history

I remember reading years ago about a company whose CEO decided that its employees or teams should compete against each other for budget the same way that businesses do in the marketplace for sales.  The idea was that many redundant teams would spring up within the company and compete against each other, and only the ones with the best ideas/performance were able to secure enough budget to sustain themselves.  If I recall rightly, it did not end well.

Unfortunately, I can't remember the name of the company nor the executive who came up with the idea, and I cannot for the life of me find any mention of this on the internet — and it's leaving me wondering if I just imagined the whole thing.

Has a company ever taken individualism to such an extreme and enacted internal "market-driven" competition between its teams or departments?

Comment: I think that might be Enron.

Comment: I don't know if you can call it "organised" but a number of conglomerates operate like this, where subsidiaries are essentially autonomous units that openly compete on the free market. Sony Mobile and Sony Imagining compete for the services of Sony Semiconductors, for instance.

Comment: IBM had a big trouble of competition for resources and customers  between their multiple (small 1400 series and large machines 7000 series) platforms around 1960. The solution they took was to design which could scale and provide a solution both small and large customers. This included deciding to not do a direct successor to the 7094, instead replace with the future 360.

Comment: You might be thinking of GM - this is how they operate their manufacturing.

Comment: Voting to close as the question seems to lack preliminary research. [Here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/stevedenning/2013/07/16/do-internal-markets-nourish-innovation-the-case-of-sears/?sh=d17b3d55b622) is an article about Sears for instance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too vague and not placed in a historical context.